# Placing hyperlink in background image

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make the background picture to have clickable links, there will be 3 language selection, when I click into it, it will redirect to respective language page. The problem now is, when I tried resize the browser, the alignment will gone haywire, the area mapping will out of the selection section. Here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUVZS.jpg

```
<html>
<style>
body { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.responsive-img {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
.responsive-img {
    background: url(<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>images/landing-bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}   
}

.outer-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#lang-en {
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#lang-malay {
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid yellow; 
}

#lang-simplified {
height: 120px;
width: 90px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid yellow;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="outer-wrapper" >
<img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>images/landing-bg.jpg" class="responsive-img" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
<div class="inner-wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 55%;">
<img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>images/blank.gif" width="400px" height="120px" id="lang-en" usemap="#Map" >

<map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="614,85,676,201">
      <area shape="rect" coords="260,86,323,202" href="#" id="lang-en">
      <area shape="rect" coords="26,87,89,202" href="#" id="lang-malay">
</map>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the yellow box?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Nope. I wanted to make the three black box to be clickable, however when I try to resize my browser the area code will be out from the black boxes

Comment: Will you provide a link to your site?

Comment: I don't think you can set percentages in the map area coordinates so I don't see how this would work without either using js or switching out to creating separate elements for the menu.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen I could not show the site because it is ip locked however,  I have into jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/69kjpz9n/2/

Answer (score 0):

css :

```
.outer-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}


.x,.y,.z {
    position:absolute;
    top:26%;
    left:74%;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.y{

    top:32%;

}
.z{

    top:40%;

}
```

html :

```
<body>
<div class="outer-wrapper" >
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/fajJXXv.jpg" class="responsive-img" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <a href="#" class="x">english</a><a href="#" class="y">spanish</a><a href="#" class="z">french</a>
<div class="inner-wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 55%;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/H3kggqB.gif" width="400px" height="120px" id="lang-en" usemap="#Map" >

<map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="614,85,676,201">
      <area shape="rect" coords="260,86,323,202" href="#" id="lang-en">
      <area shape="rect" coords="26,87,89,202" href="#" id="lang-malay">
</map>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/souraj/69kjpz9n/4/

i think this is what you need. if not please let me know. 
now you have to make the necessary changes to position the links according to the screen resolution.

Comment: I tried, once i resize the browser, the alignment ran away

Comment: which alignment are you talking about?are you talking about the alignment of the links inside three small boxes?

Comment: what I meant is, when I tried to resize the browser, the hyperlink will not be the same as it is before. You will know what I mean when u put `code` <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fajJXXv.jpg" class="responsive-img" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" id="lang-en">

The box will change place when you resize the browser

Comment: where do you want to place the image "i.imgur.com/fajJXXv.jpg" in the website?please tell me the proper design which you want.

Comment: The link given is a background image, and u see 3 black boxes those are the buttons that should be a hyperlink to navigate to somewhere else.

Comment: I have placed the links in the small boxes according to your need. Now you have to change the position of those links with media query when those are not in a proper position. Also you may have to change the font-size using media query.